# Graphics trouble

Tags: graphics

I love Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (installed after a reformat of the drive), but every time it updates, it alters my graphics with unviewable results
[pic of screen after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW70x.jpg)

and I have to reinstall. How can I stabilize my graphics settings?

Comment: 20.04 Ubuntu studio

Comment: I format the hd

Comment: Yes I erased the hard drive and install the Ubuntu studio 20.04 several times throughout the week, I got the 19.10 for long time without issues but now I can’t because it updates itself

Comment: well, more info about what graphic drivers cause this could be helpful. Are you installing OEM drivers? What graphics hardware do you have? Like a GPU, or integrated graphics? would blacklisting the update be a preferred solution? Also, if you can get to that torn graphics page, then you could probably fix the issue without reinstalling, but that might be beyond the scope of this question.